# How to use SEC_ASN1_SAVE?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I need to get full DER encoded item from `SEQUENCE`. But I've got `Segmentation fault: 11`. What is wrong?

If I comment line with `SEC_ASN1_SAVE` it works ok for `version`, but I need to get `derVersion`

```
typedef struct {
    SecAsn1Item derVersion;
    SecAsn1Item version;
} ASN1_TEST;

const SecAsn1Template kTestTemplate[] = {
    {SEC_ASN1_SEQUENCE, 0, NULL, sizeof(ASN1_TEST)},
    {SEC_ASN1_SAVE, offsetof(ASN1_TEST, derVersion)},
    {SEC_ASN1_INTEGER, offsetof(ASN1_TEST, version)},
    {0}
};

void ParseASN1(){
    const char der[] = "\x30\x05\x02\x03\x01\x00\x01";

    SecAsn1CoderRef coder = NULL;
    OSStatus status = SecAsn1CoderCreate(&coder);
    if (status) {
        THROW_EXCEPTION("SecAsn1CoderCreate");
    }

    ASN1_TEST test;
    status = SecAsn1Decode(
                  coder,
                  (CK_BYTE_PTR)der, 7,
                  kTestTemplate,
                  &test
                  );
    if (status) {
        SecAsn1CoderRelease(coder);

        THROW_EXCEPTION("SecAsn1Decode");
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Test.version: %lu\n", test.version.Length);
    fprintf(stdout, "Test.derVersion: %lu\n", test.derVersion.Length);

    SecAsn1CoderRelease(coder);
}
```

Here are some links with code I found.

[NSS_TBSCertificate structure](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55179.1/libsecurity_asn1/Security/X509Templates.h.auto.html)

[kSecAsn1TBSCertificateTemplate template](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55179.1/libsecurity_asn1/Security/X509Templates.c.auto.html)

Comment: Hi, I'm also dealing with similar issue. Perhaps you can try and help me in the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59373529/parsing-der-format-data-using-secasn1decode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem.

I had to add `memset(&test, 0, sizeof(ASN1_TEST));` after `test` declaration