# parsing DER format data using SecAsn1Decode

Tags: security, cocoa, core-foundation, asn.1

I'm trying to use `SecAsn1Decode` in order to parse the following DER encoded data.

However, I failed to define the template for this struct (represented by `SecAsn1Template`).

perhaps anybody can explain how to create a template for the following DER structure :

here's the binary raw data (DER formatted)

```
30 81 8E 31 0B 30 09 06  03 55 04 06 13 02 49 4C
31 0F 30 0D 06 03 55 04  08 0C 06 69 73 72 61 65
6C 31 0C 30 0A 06 03 55  04 07 0C 03 54 4C 56 31
0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 0A  0C 02 54 53 31 1E 30 1C
06 03 55 04 0B 0C 15 43  41 5F 63 65 72 74 69 66
69 63 61 74 65 5F 73 65  72 76 65 72 31 1B 30 19
06 03 55 04 03 0C 12 61  61 61 61 61 61 61 4D 61
63 42 6F 6F 6B 5F 50 72  6F 31 16 30 14 06 09 2A
86 48 86 F7 0D 01 09 01  16 07 7A 40 7A 2E 63 6F
6D
```

and here's the interpretation of this data using asn1 java decoder 
https://lapo.it/asn1js

```
EQUENCE (7 elem)
  SET (1 elem)
    SEQUENCE (2 elem)
      OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.5.4.6 countryName (X.520 DN component)
      PrintableString aa
  SET (1 elem)
    SEQUENCE (2 elem)
      OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.5.4.8 stateOrProvinceName (X.520 DN component)
      UTF8String aaaaaa
  SET (1 elem)
    SEQUENCE (2 elem)
      OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.5.4.7 localityName (X.520 DN component)
      UTF8String aaa
  SET (1 elem)
    SEQUENCE (2 elem)
      OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.5.4.10 organizationName (X.520 DN component)
      UTF8String TS
  SET (1 elem)
    SEQUENCE (2 elem)
      OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.5.4.11 organizationalUnitName (X.520 DN component)
      UTF8String CA_certificate_server
  SET (1 elem)
    SEQUENCE (2 elem)
      OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.5.4.3 commonName (X.520 DN component)
      UTF8String aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  SET (1 elem)
    SEQUENCE (2 elem)
      OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.9.1 emailAddress (PKCS #9. Deprecated, use an altName extension instead)
      IA5String a@a.com
```

Comment: this is an X.500 Distinguished name format which is defined in RFC2253, Section 2: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2253#section-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is DER/BER TLV data.

Here is the detailed data parsing with https://iso8583.info/lib/ISO/8825/1/BER/TLVs

```
TLVs:#"30818E310B300906035504061302494C310F300D06035504080C06697372..6F6D" # ASN.1, Basic Encoding Rules (BER), Tag + Length + Value (TLV) series
- x30:#"30818E310B300906035504061302494C310F300D06035504080C06697372..6F6D" # SEQUENCE
  - tag: "30"
  - len: "818E" #  // 142
  - val:#"310B300906035504061302494C310F300D06035504080C0669737261656C..6F6D"
    - x31:#"310B300906035504061302494C" # SET
      - tag: "31"
      - len: "0B" #  // 11
      - val:#"300906035504061302494C"
        - x30:#"300906035504061302494C" # SEQUENCE
          - tag: "30"
          - len: "09" #  // 9
          - val:#"06035504061302494C"
            - x06:#"0603550406" # Object Identifier (OID)
              - tag: "06"
              - len: "03" #  // 3
              - val: "550406" #  // 2 5 4 6 - joint-iso-itu-t.ds.attributeType.countryName
            - x13:#"1302494C" # PrintableString
              - tag: "13"
              - len: "02" #  // 2
              - val: "494C" #  // IL
    - x31:#"310F300D06035504080C0669737261656C" # SET
      - tag: "31"
      - len: "0F" #  // 15
      - val:#"300D06035504080C0669737261656C"
        - x30:#"300D06035504080C0669737261656C" # SEQUENCE
          - tag: "30"
          - len: "0D" #  // 13
          - val:#"06035504080C0669737261656C"
            - x06:#"0603550408" # Object Identifier (OID)
              - tag: "06"
              - len: "03" #  // 3
              - val: "550408" #  // 2 5 4 8
            - x0C:#"0C0669737261656C" # UTF8String
              - tag: "0C"
              - len: "06" #  // 6
              - val: "69737261656C" #  // israel
    - x31:#"310C300A06035504070C03544C56" # SET
      - tag: "31"
      - len: "0C" #  // 12
      - val:#"300A06035504070C03544C56"
        - x30:#"300A06035504070C03544C56" # SEQUENCE
          - tag: "30"
          - len: "0A" #  // 10
          - val:#"06035504070C03544C56"
            - x06:#"0603550407" # Object Identifier (OID)
              - tag: "06"
              - len: "03" #  // 3
              - val: "550407" #  // 2 5 4 7 - joint-iso-itu-t.ds.attributeType.localityName
            - x0C:#"0C03544C56" # UTF8String
              - tag: "0C"
              - len: "03" #  // 3
              - val: "544C56" #  // TLV
    - x31:#"310B3009060355040A0C025453" # SET
      - tag: "31"
      - len: "0B" #  // 11
      - val:#"3009060355040A0C025453"
        - x30:#"3009060355040A0C025453" # SEQUENCE
          - tag: "30"
          - len: "09" #  // 9
          - val:#"060355040A0C025453"
            - x06:#"060355040A" # Object Identifier (OID)
              - tag: "06"
              - len: "03" #  // 3
              - val: "55040A" #  // 2 5 4 10 - joint-iso-itu-t.ds.attributeType.organizationName
            - x0C:#"0C025453" # UTF8String
              - tag: "0C"
              - len: "02" #  // 2
              - val: "5453" #  // TS
    - x31:#"311E301C060355040B0C1543415F63657274696669636174655F736572766572" # SET
      - tag: "31"
      - len: "1E" #  // 30
      - val:#"301C060355040B0C1543415F63657274696669636174655F736572766572"
        - x30:#"301C060355040B0C1543415F63657274696669636174655F736572766572" # SEQUENCE
          - tag: "30"
          - len: "1C" #  // 28
          - val:#"060355040B0C1543415F63657274696669636174655F736572766572"
            - x06:#"060355040B" # Object Identifier (OID)
              - tag: "06"
              - len: "03" #  // 3
              - val: "55040B" #  // 2 5 4 11 - joint-iso-itu-t.ds.attributeType.organizationUnitName
            - x0C:#"0C1543415F63657274696669636174655F736572766572" # UTF8String
              - tag: "0C"
              - len: "15" #  // 21
              - val: "43415F63657274696669636174655F736572766572" #  // CA_certificate_server
    - x31:#"311B301906035504030C12616161616161614D6163426F6F6B5F50726F" # SET
      - tag: "31"
      - len: "1B" #  // 27
      - val:#"301906035504030C12616161616161614D6163426F6F6B5F50726F"
        - x30:#"301906035504030C12616161616161614D6163426F6F6B5F50726F" # SEQUENCE
          - tag: "30"
          - len: "19" #  // 25
          - val:#"06035504030C12616161616161614D6163426F6F6B5F50726F"
            - x06:#"0603550403" # Object Identifier (OID)
              - tag: "06"
              - len: "03" #  // 3
              - val: "550403" #  // 2 5 4 3 - joint-iso-itu-t.ds.attributeType.commonName
            - x0C:#"0C12616161616161614D6163426F6F6B5F50726F" # UTF8String
              - tag: "0C"
              - len: "12" #  // 18
              - val: "616161616161614D6163426F6F6B5F50726F" #  // aaaaaaaMacBook_Pro
    - x31:#"3116301406092A864886F70D01090116077A407A2E636F6D" # SET
      - tag: "31"
      - len: "16" #  // 22
      - val:#"301406092A864886F70D01090116077A407A2E636F6D"
        - x30:#"301406092A864886F70D01090116077A407A2E636F6D" # SEQUENCE
          - tag: "30"
          - len: "14" #  // 20
          - val:#"06092A864886F70D01090116077A407A2E636F6D"
            - x06:#"06092A864886F70D010901" # Object Identifier (OID)
              - tag: "06"
              - len: "09" #  // 9
              - val: "2A864886F70D010901" #  // 1 2 840 113549 1 9 1 - iso.member-body.us.rsadsi.pkcs.pkcs-9.emailAddress
            - x16:#"16077A407A2E636F6D" # IA5String
              - tag: "16"
              - len: "07" #  // 7
              - val: "7A407A2E636F6D" #  // z@z.com
```